# why cv2.imwrite() changes the color of pics?

Tags: python, opencv, opencv3.0

I have the following piece of code:

```
imgs = glob.glob('/home/chipin/heart/tray.png')
current_img = io.imread(imgs[0])
cv2.imwrite('/home/chipin/heart/01.png', current_img[0:511,0:511])
```

The size of picture is 512*512, after being saved, a blue picture turns yellow. It seems that a channel is abandoned. I really don't know why.

Here is the value of current_img:

[image: value of current_img]

Comment: I assume the `io.imread` is the one from skimage?

Comment: If so, then the issue is in the fact that [`skimage.io.imread`](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.io.html#skimage.io.imread) loads image as RGB, but numpy assumes the image to be [BGR](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d4/da8/group__imgcodecs.html#gabbc7ef1aa2edfaa87772f1202d67e0ce). This means that blue and red planes get flipped. Why don't you just use  `cv2.imread` to load the image instead?

Comment: thanks I suppose so.And how can I correct it please?

Comment: Either use `cv2.imread`, which will read in BGR format as well (this is the default for OpenCV), or use `cv2.cvtColor` to convert from RGB to BGR.

Comment: Oh, and the last channel full of zeros -- looks like transparency. In that case it's RGBA <-> BGRA.

Comment: thank you sooo much

Comment: No problem :) Remember, documentation is your friend ;) | BTW, on StackOverflow, it's customary to upvote answers you find helpful (that's the little upwards pointing triangle next to the answer). Also, if it's an answer to your question and you deem it the best one, there's a little checkmark that let's you "accept" it.

Comment: For which reason did OpenCV choose to swap channels in RGB? What's the rationale in complicating it more: there are enough color spaces: RGB, LAB, CMYK, HUV... so why create BGR? :) Would you know the historical reason @DanMašek?

Answer (score 147, accepted):

Your problem is in the fact that [`skimage.io.imread`](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.io.html#skimage.io.imread) loads image as RGB (or RGBA), but OpenCV assumes the image to be [BGR or BGRA](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d4/da8/group__imgcodecs.html#gabbc7ef1aa2edfaa87772f1202d67e0ce) (BGR is the default OpenCV colour format). This means that blue and red planes get flipped.

---

### 3 Channel Images

Let's try this out with the following simple test image:

[image: Input image]

---

First let's try your original algorithm:

```
import skimage.io
import cv2

img = skimage.io.imread('sample.png')
cv2.imwrite('sample_out_1.png', img)
```

We get the following result:

[image: Result 1]

As you can see, red and blue channels are visibly swapped.

---

The first approach, assuming you want to still use skimage to read and cv2 to write is to use [`cv2.cvtColor`](http://docs.opencv.org/3.2.0/d7/d1b/group__imgproc__misc.html#ga397ae87e1288a81d2363b61574eb8cab) to convert from RGB to BGR.

Since the new OpenCV docs don't mention Python syntax, in this case you can also use the [appropriate reference for 2.4.x](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html?highlight=cvtcolor#cvtcolor).

```
import skimage.io
import cv2

img = skimage.io.imread('sample.png')
cv2.imwrite('sample_out_2.png', cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR))
```

Now we get the following output:

[image: Result 2]

---

An alternative is to just use OpenCV -- use [`cv2.imread`](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d4/da8/group__imgcodecs.html#ga288b8b3da0892bd651fce07b3bbd3a56) to load the image. In this case we're working only with BGR images.

**NB:** Not providing any flags means `cv2.IMREAD_COLOR` is used by default -- i.e. image is always loaded as a 3-channel image (dropping any potential alpha channels).

```
import cv2

img = cv2.imread('sample.png')
cv2.imwrite('sample_out_3.png', img)
```

[image: Result 3]

---

### 4 Channel Images

From your screenshot, it appears that you have a 4 channel image. This would mean RGBA in skimage, and BGRA in OpenCV. The principles would be similar.

- Either use colour conversion code `cv2.COLOR_RGBA2BGRA`
- Or use `cv2.imread` with flag `cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED`

Comment: Hmm, maybe I shouldn't have made the sample image rotationally symmetrical. :)

Comment: Found this useful as I read with `cv2.imread` but display with `matplotlib`. I find it weird though that opencv uses BGR.

Comment: Okay, just read this: https://www.learnopencv.com/why-does-opencv-use-bgr-color-format/. And apparently OpenCV uses BGR because of horse ass.

Comment: @DanMašek well explained.Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

The image on input (as a png) is in RGB order but the image in memory (as a cv::Mat) is in BGR order.
Use `cv2.imread()` for input. So, imread() will internally convert from rgb to bgr and imwrite() will do the opposite, all under the hood.

Here's how you do it:

```
current_img = cv2.imread('/home/chipin/heart/tray.png')
cv2.imwrite('/home/chipin/heart/01.png', current_img)
```