# cv2.imwrite and pyplot.imshow displaying grey scale images differently

Tags: python, opencv, matplotlib, plot

I have a bunch of medical images in a `hdf5` file.

```
 path_to_data = "data/train_large_axial_350_x_350.hdf5"
 data = h5py.File(path_to_data,"r")
 image_list = data["images"]
 image = image_list[5]
```

If I do

```
 cv2.imwrite("maps/image.jpg", image)
```

I get:

[image]

But, if I do

```
plt.imshow(image)
```

I get:

[image]

What is the cause of this and how can I plot the image so that it looks like that which is produced by `cv2.imwrite`?

Comment: What type is `image`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [why cv2.imwrite() changes the color of pics?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42406338/why-cv2-imwrite-changes-the-color-of-pics)

Comment: color order BGR, RGB

Comment: @abhilb It's a grayscale image -- even if it's 3-channel, alll the channels are identical, so the order is irrelevant in this case.

Comment: Maybe you have a default matplotlib colormap active. What is the result for `plt.imshow(img, cmap='gray')`?

Comment: plt.imshow(image_list[0], cmap='gray') produces the same result

Comment: image is a numpy.ndarray

Answer (score 0):

This is because `matplotlib` plots the image in the range of the gray values of your image. For example, if your image contains gray values between 21 to 88, then matplotlib plots it with this range, and not between 0 and 255.

This can be fixed by the following:

```
# from matplotlib import cm    
plt.imshow(image, cmap=cm.gray, vmin=0, vmax=255)
```

For a more in-depth discussion, check out [this](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/7221/) github issue.