# Unable to resize image using OpenCV after converting pdf to images using pdf2image package

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, computer-vision

Unable to resize image using cv2 after converting pdf to images using pdf2image package.

The code is

```
import os
import cv2
from pdf2image import convert_from_path
pdf_files = [filename for filename in os.listdir(
    os.getcwd()) if filename.endswith('.pdf')]
for pdf_file in pdf_files:
    images = convert_from_path(pdf_file, 400)
    for i, image in enumerate(images):
        fname = pdf_file+'_image'+str(i)+'.jpg'
        fname = cv2.resize(fname, (3400, 4400))
        image.save(fname, "JPEG")
```

Error is

```
fname = cv2.resize(fname, (3400, 4400))
TypeError: Expected Ptr<cv::UMat> for argument 'src'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to resize your filename in this line of your code:

```
fname = cv2.resize(fname, (3400, 4400))
```

Replace the above line with:

```
image = cv2.resize(image, (3400, 4400))
```

To save the image the command will be `cv2.imwrite(fname, image)`

Also you would need to convert your images to arrays. For that, you have to `import numpy`. Here is the complete code:

```
import os
import cv2
import numpy as np 
from pdf2image import convert_from_path
pdf_files = [filename for filename in os.listdir(
    os.getcwd()) if filename.endswith('.pdf')]
for pdf_file in pdf_files:
    images = convert_from_path(pdf_file, 400)
    for i, image in enumerate(images):
        fname = pdf_file+'_image'+str(i)+'.jpg'
        image = np.array(image)
        image = cv2.resize(image, (3400, 4400))
        cv2.imwrite(fname, image)
```

Comment: I've updated my answer. Does this work for you?

Comment: It worked, but the yellow color in pdf is blue in converted image. Is there any mistake?

Comment: `cv2.imwrite(fname, cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR))` should fix it. You can find more details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42406338/why-cv2-imwrite-changes-the-color-of-pics)